# Recursive function C multiplying by 4 problem

Tags: c, recursion

I'm supposed to write a program in C for school where I multiply by 4 but I can't get it to work. When I type 2 I get 20, when I type 3 it's 84, when I type 4 it's 340 and so on, why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multi(int i)
{
    if (i == 1) {
        return 4; 
    } 
    if (i == 0) {
    return 0;
    }
    if (i > 1) {
    return (multi(i-1)*4)+4;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("type a numer for multiplication by 4\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%d * 4 is %d\n",i, multi(i));
}
```

Comment: Why would you need recursion to multiply a number by 4? Just multiply, you don't even need a function. Do you actually mean x^4?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return (multi(i-1))+4;`?

Comment: I know I don't need to use a recursive function but this was my assignment cause we are learning recursive functions and I could get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying `X` by `Y` is adding `X`   `Y` number of times.

```
X * Y = X + X + X ...Y times
```

So change

```
return (multi(i-1)*4)+4;
```

to

```
return multi(i-1) + 4;
```

and it will work as intended for multiplication by 4.

However, if you want to raise `X` to the power of `Y`, you have to multiply `X`  `Y` number of times.

```
X to the power of Y = X * X * X...Y times
```

In this case, there are a couple of more changes you have to make to your code which I leave to you as an exercise.

Comment: does that multiply by `4`? or raise to power `4`?

Comment: Adding X Y times multiples by Y, but multiplying X Y times raises X to the power of Y. I will update the answer to include that as well.

Comment: There is no reason to write such obscure code, not even for learning purposes.